# Extending User Model Django, IntegrityError

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to extend the `User` model to create a `Profile` model. The following code successfully displays a form with the additional fields I specified as `location` and `bio`. But when I submit the form only the original `username`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, and `password` fields are stored in the database at http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin, none of my custom fields are stored in the Profile section I added to admin . I also get the following error:

```
IntegrityError at /accounts/register/
NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_profile.user_id
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/
Django Version: 1.11.2
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_profile.user_id
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 328
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True)

    class Meta:
        model = User #model User comes with username, email, first name, last name , pass1 and pass2 fields
        fields = (
            'username',
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        )

    def save(self, commit = True):
        user =  super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit = False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name =  self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email =  self.cleaned_data['email']


        if commit:
            user.save()

            return user

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('location','bio')
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect  
from .forms import RegistrationForm,ProfileForm



def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        profile_form = ProfileForm()


    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    # /accounts/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'accounts'),

    # /accounts/register/
    url(r'^register/$',  views.register, name='register'),

    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'accounts/login.html'}, name='login'),
]
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Profile)
# Register your models here.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set the relation manually then your view should look like this:

```
    if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        user_object = form.save()
        a = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        a.user = user_object
        a.save()
        return redirect('login')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't do register and profile `POST`  at a time.because your profile model is `1to1`field  it belongs to `User`which means existing user can create one user profile.So initially user should create their registered account than only they can create profile.

Comment: You can save user form then assign user to profile validate profile form and then save.

Comment: @wololoooo that is what I'm saying. First you have to save user then only you can create profile for that user